# Error in write ArrayList String to File

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to write an arraylist string list to a file. The arraylist string is actually a string converted from twitter JSON and I am trying to write the tweet text into the file.

However, I keep getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Writer.write(Unknown Source)
    at kr.ac.uos.datamining.test.main(test.java:32)
```

The code for the whole class are below:

```
    package kr.ac.uos.datamining;

    import java.io.File; 
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException; 
    import java.io.*;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import kr.ac.uos.datamining.JSONParser; 
    import kr.ac.uos.datamining.Tweet; 
    import kr.ac.uos.datamining.User;

    public class test {

    public static List <String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException, InterruptedException, SQLException {

        JSONParser j = new JSONParser(new File("D:/curl-7.32.0/samsunggalaxy-01-23-2014.txt"));
        ArrayList<Tweet> tweets = j.getTweets();

        for(Tweet tweet : tweets){
            list.add(tweet.getText());
        }

        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("D:/samsunggalaxy.txt");
        for (String tweet: list) {
Line 32   writer.write(tweet);
        }
        writer.close();   
    }
    }
```

Since it is said as Unknown Source, is it the problem with the `String tweet: list` line? 
I tried to change it to `String str: list` but its not working as well

Comment: Do you validate that list has something inside?

Comment: Some tweets have a null text. That's why you get an NPE.

Comment: When I used the list to write in MySQL instead of textfile, it was working. So I think that the list is working..

Comment: @JB Nizet is there anyway to deal with the null text?

Comment: Yes. You can use `if (tweet == null)` and decide what you want to do in that case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way that you got a `NullPoineterException` is that your text is null, so validate what you want to write before writing it.

```
for (String tweet: list) {
    if(tweet != null || !tweet.equals("")) {
        writer.write(tweet);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems one of your tweet objects is null. This is the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `String tweet` is null, so I'd check your `Tweet.getText()` method to ensure it never returns null.